# TypeError: header name must be a valid http token in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;

var server = http.createServer(function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'});
    res.end('<h1>This is hello word</h1>');
});

server.listen(port,hostname,function () {
    console.log(`server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Error I have got, node version I use is v4.4.7
[image]

Comment: So you're saying that `Foo\nBar` is something that Node is injecting into your code?

Comment: that was the fix I have tried, updated the image

Comment: Again, the error is showing the issue: the header you're trying to set seems to be using a C-cedilla (`Ç`), not a plain C.

Comment: It works no idea, now it works with all combiation "content-type, Content-Type, Content-type"

Comment: one more question, each time when i change the code and refresh it is not reflected, i have to restart server.. is that needed?

Comment: Yes, that's normal. If you want it to reload automatically, you can use something [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).